# Open API Spec3 - How to display a drop-down or a way to select an input from multiple inputs?

Tags: spring, springdoc, springdoc-openui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am working on `Spring Boot & Open API Spec3` using `springdoc-openapi-ui`.  How to display a drop-down or a way to select an input from multiple inputs? I went through https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/685, I need something like this.

My organization allows only 8 query parameters, we're using pagination, so **page, size, sort (by multiple fields) and order (multiple fields)**. This all consumes 4 query Parameters and left only 4 to used, since for few of the endpoints, consumer wants to use many parameters as optional to fetch the data.

If somehow in `api-doc` if I can create option to select multiple things like Pagination and Sorting into one then it will be great.

The same question have been opened up here: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/535

Springdoc team has to constantly looking and resolving the issues. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Your question is not related to springdoc.

The swagger documentation explains clearly, how to display multiple choices:

- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/

Comment: It doesn't work with Spring.